# Installing Ubuntu on Asus A43SM

Tags: installation, boot-failure, asus

i've Asus Laptop A43SM
the specifications can be seen [here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=A43SM&p=3&os=).

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop, but something wrong is happening. When I boot up Ubuntu on this laptop the first screen Ubuntu loader shows up,
but then it freezes; I can't do anything but push the power button.

I've tried to use a usb drive and a CD but that doesn't help.

Anyone can tell me how to install Ubuntu ?

Comment: My first question would be: What is displayed on the screen when the computer freezes? Second would be: Do you have any other bootable devices installed in the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

When it starts booting press <kbd>esc</kbd> to stop it for a while, and then press <kbd>F6</kbd> to turn on `nomodoset`

I have the same laptop as you and it works fine.