# Desktop - Unity - problem

Tags: unity, freeze

I upgraded software couple days ago. Now I have a problem with my desktop. I'm attaching a print screen to show what I mean.

[image]

<sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version.</sup>

Comment: Interesting effect! Can you tell us what graphics card you use and the system set-up (PC/MAC) to help people work out what your problem could be.

Comment: I forgot to add that I have had this effect after closing the windows. I have Nvidia GeForce GT 325M and Intel HD - Asus N61JV. I hasn't install any drivers to them yet.

Comment: I'll reply in a few minutes, a bit busy at the moment sorting out my wife's email account

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

OK, this could be your answer,

After logging in to Ubuntu, Click on the System Settings icon on the Launch Bar and Click on the Software and Updates icon.

[image]

Wait for that window to appear, it will look something like this:

[image]

Select the latest driver that you want to use. as you can see I chose the 313-updates (proprietary) driver, whilst yours is probably set to Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver. Click on the **Apply Changes** button and wait for the drivers to be installed or activated, then click close.

Next, start Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings-313-updates
```

When that completes, enter the following command:

```
nvidia-settings
```

This will bring up the NVIDIA settings tool

Hope this helps.

## Solution 2

I have found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131863/installing-ubuntu-on-asus-a43sm/156375#156375) which may help:

When you reboot your computer, as it is booting press <kbd>esc</kbd> to stop it for a while, and then press <kbd>F6</kbd> to turn on `nomodoset`.

I have no idea what this does, bit has worked for some Asus machines

## Solution 3

As this problem started after an update, you may have to do the following: ([see here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze#Problem:__Freeze_began_after_a_system_update))

Regression bugs that freeze the system reliably are ironically the most productive to solve.

If you updated your system and it started to freeze, start reverting package updates backwards until the freezes stop occurring.

```
1). try is booting an earlier kernel. 
    a). Hold down the left shift key during boot, so that the grub bootloader 
        menu comes up. 
    b). Look through the set of available kernels for one you used prior to the update; 
    c). boot that and attempt to reproduce the freeze.
```

If it does not freeze, then you now have a "Good" and "Bad" kernel and can proceed with a [kernel bisection search](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBisection) to isolate what patch caused the failure.

<sub>(Yes, compiling kernels sounds intimidating and time consuming, but stick with it - the process is well documented and it has a **very** high likelihood of narrowing it to a specific cause!)</sub>

Comment: I followed your advice and I have now this kind of error
http://i41.tinypic.com/iyitqf.jpg

Comment: Try the Proprietary, Tested Driver.

Comment: I tried and Ubuntu was suspending after I logged in. I had to uninstall it.

Comment: OK back to the drawing board. I'll try and find something else that will help.

Comment: I have added a second possible solution which may help to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I have continued searching and have found a final solution. If all these don't work, you may have to consider a new install rather than an upgrade... but this would be as a last resort as you will loose all your settings, have to download all the programmes again and .... Aghhh! :D

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked. I think I have to consider reinstall Ubuntu, but maybe at first I will wait for another updates.